# Creating sitemaps in js

Tags: javascript, xml, sitemap

I want to create a sitemap in xml. Currently, in the js file, I downloaded information about the last modifications, website addresses from the api and I want to display it in the xml file.

My js file looks like,
where links this is array with information about site

```
    let sitemapEntries = links.map((link) => {
    return `
            <url><loc>https://websiteName.com/${link.slug}</loc></url> <br/>
            <lastmod>${link.published_at.substring(0,10)}</lastmod>
            <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
            <priority>0.5</priority>
        ` 
        
})


let sitemap = `<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
xmlns:image="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" 
xmlns:video="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">${sitemapEntries.join('')}
</urlset>`


document.querySelector('#linksresponse').innerHTML = sitemap.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
  .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
  .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
  .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
  .replace(/'/g, '&apos;');

});
```

my xml file looks like

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<main xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
    <script src="./scripts/sitemap.js"></script>
    <div id="linksresponse"></div>
</main>
```

and this is fragment what I get
[image]

Is it possible to make my sitemap look like this?
[image]

Comment: I agree with Quentin, you'll need to create the sitemap.xml on the server, or have a server script the returns XML with content type text/xml

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you **don't** have a Sitemap XML file.

You have an XHTML file which you dynamically modify to include an XHTML representation of the source code of a Sitemap XML file.

You **could** step through the characters of the generated source for and add extra tags (so, for example, instead of `&lt;url&gt;`  you have `<code class="start-tag">&lt;url&gt;</code>` and then add a stylesheet to say `code.start-tag { font-family: monospace; color: blue; }` but that would only give you something that *looks* like the way a browser would render a real Sitemap XML.

Sitemaps are generally processed by tools (or at least parts of bigger tools) which aren't HTML aware and certainly won't execute client-side JS in them. You might have it in mind that that code you've written will only be used to generate code that can be copy/pasted into a real Sitemap XML file but I get the impression that isn't the case.

You should change your strategy so that your file is generated outside of the browser, either with server-side code or a static site generator.